# Detect if is in viewport using verge

Tags: javascript, jquery

I consider using [verge by ryanve](https://github.com/ryanve/verge) to detect wether some elements appear to be inside the current viewport.

As I did not find any tutorials on how to use verge, I wanted to try it out for myself. As a very basic example I want to use [`inViewport(elem)`](https://github.com/ryanve/verge#inviewport) to detect wether my image is inside the viewport or not and manipulate it.

I have tried a basic example, which does not work:

```
if(verge.inViewport(target)) {
  target.show();
}
```

[**JSFIDDLE DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/Len4Laet/)

Comment: It works, but `show()` acts so fast that you cannot detect the change. Try this https://jsfiddle.net/Len4Laet/1/

Comment: I have created an example fading it in slowly, but I thought it did not work. So I have rewritten it for this demo. thats awesome to hear, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code does actually work, like stated out by @AdamAzad in the comments:

```
if(verge.inViewport(target)) {
  target.show();
}
```